# can inter-widget communication with state management

Tags: redux, widget

I have a react application which has multiple widgets and a user can open multiple widgets at the same time.  And two widgets can communicate with each other.  Is it possible to achieve the feature with state management or redux?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make data available everywhere is to use providers. You can wrap the data in it with a useState, make the setX available in your components. Redux can also let you do something similar, but it's less simple. Your call!

Comment: Other than this, is there any new process or techniques for inter widget communication ?

Comment: Maybe by transmitting callbacks from a parent widget to the children through props, or with events. By using a reducer (useReducer) you'll have more control too. In my opinion the provider + useState or UseReducer is the cleanest / simplest way. But that's just my point of view according to what I know. If you're looking for "THE official and perfect way to do this", I don't think there's such thing unfortunately. I'd be interested though.